# Get Facebook Long Time access Token using Laravel Socialite

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel Socialite for my laravel application to login with Facebook. I have seen its documentation, but I haven't found any thing related to getting long time access token. Can any body let me know how can I get long time access token using Laravel Socialite?

The access token that we receive using Socialite says `[expiresIn] => 5174875`. 
What is the Unit of this? Is it short term or long term access token?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! But have you read my question dear?

Comment: It should answer at least the last two questions. And how extending tokens _basically_ works, is also explained there. So now you either go look up whether LS implements this already via a specific method or something, or you start implementing it yourself as described.

Comment: I'd assume that ExpiresIn is in seconds (It's also commented in the Socalite code 'The number of seconds the access token is valid for.' found at socialite/src/Two/User.php), which when you convert to days it's 59.8 days. A long lived Facebook token lasts for 60 days, so this looks correct to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You already have a long-lived token.**

`[expiresIn]` is the number of **seconds** until this access token expires.

5,174,875 seconds is (approximately):

- 86,247 minutes
- 1,437 hours
- 59 days

Long-lived access tokens are good for about 60 days, thus the token is long-lived.

Source: [facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)